# Bank simulation using ArrayList

Tags: java, object-oriented, finance

Problem Statement:

> Design a `BALANCE` class with account number, balance and date of last
>   updation. Consider a `TRANSACTION` class with account number, date of
>   transaction, amount and transaction type. Check whether the amount is
>   available or not in case of a withdrawal. Transaction object will make
>   necessary updates in the `BALANCE` class.

## `Balance` class

```
package balance;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Balance {
    private double balance;
    private Date date;
    private long accountNum;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Balance(long aNo, double money, Date aDate) {
        accountNum = aNo;
        balance = money;
        date = (Date) aDate.clone();
        System.out.println("New account created with account no :" + accountNum);
        System.out.println("Opening balance rs. " + balance);
        System.out.println("Account created on " + date.toString());
    }

    public Balance(Balance b) {
        balance = b.balance;
        date = b.date;
        accountNum = b.accountNum;
    }

    public Balance() {

    }

    public long getAccountNum() {
        return accountNum;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "A/C no.: " + accountNum + "\nCurrent balance: " + balance
                + "\nLast date of update: " + date;

    }

}
```

## `Bank` class to operate on `Balance` class, containing an `ArrayList` of `Balance` objects

```
package balance;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Bank {

    private ArrayList<Balance> balanceList;
    Iterator<Balance> itr;

    public Bank() {
        balanceList = new ArrayList<Balance>();
    }

    public void newAccount(Balance e) {
        balanceList.add(e);
    }

    public Balance searchAccount(long accountNum) {
        itr = balanceList.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Balance b = new Balance(itr.next());
            if (b.getAccountNum() == accountNum)
                return b;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public long getBalanceListSize() {
        return balanceList.size();
    }
}
```

## `Transaction` class to operate on a `Bank`

```
package balance;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Transaction {

    private String transactionType;
    private double amount;
    private long accountNum;
    private Date date;
    private Bank b;
    private Balance balance = new Balance();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Transaction() {
        b = new Bank();
    }

    public void transaction(long accountNum, String transactionType,
            double amount) {
        this.accountNum= accountNum;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.amount = amount;
        date = new Date();
        operation();
    }

    private void operation() {

        if (transactionType.equalsIgnoreCase("Opening")) {
            if (amount < 0) {
                System.out.println("Opening balance cannot be less than zero.");
                return;
            }

            balance = new Balance(b.getBalanceListSize() + 1, amount, date);
            b.newAccount(balance);
        }

        else if (transactionType.equalsIgnoreCase("withdraw")) {
            balance = b.searchAccount(accountNum);
            if (balance == null) {
                System.out.println("Account not found");
                return;
            }
            if (balance.getBalance() < amount) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient Balance.");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Balance before transaction:");
            System.out.println(balance.toString());
            balance.setBalance(balance.getBalance() - amount);
            System.out.println("Balance after transaction:\n"
                    + balance.toString());
        }

        else if (transactionType.equalsIgnoreCase("deposit")) {
            balance = b.searchAccount(accountNum);
            if (balance == null) {
                System.out.println("Account not found");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Balance before transaction:");
            System.out.println(balance.toString());
            balance.setBalance(balance.getBalance() + amount);
            System.out.println("Balance after transaction:\n"
                    + balance.toString());
        }

        else if (transactionType.equalsIgnoreCase("showInfo")) {
            balance = b.searchAccount(accountNum);
            if (balance == null) {
                System.out.println("Account not found");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(balance.toString());
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

## `BankDemo` class with `main()`

```
package balance;

import java.util.*;

public class BankDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String choice, ch, operation;
        Transaction transac = new Transaction();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double amount;
        long accountNo;

        do {
            System.out.println("1. New account");
            System.out.println("2. Transaction");
            System.out.println("3. View Account Information");
            System.out.println("q. Exit");
            System.out.println("choice:");
            choice = sc.next();
            switch (choice) {

            case "1":
                double openingBalance;

                System.out.println("Enter the opening balance :");
                openingBalance = sc.nextDouble();
                transac.transaction(0, "Opening", openingBalance);
                break;

            case "2":
                System.out.println("a. Deposit");
                System.out.println("b. Withdraw");
                ch = sc.next();
                if (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
                    operation = "Deposit";
                else if (ch.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
                    operation = "Withdraw";
                else {
                    operation = "Invalid option";
                }
                System.out.println("Account Number:");
                accountNo = sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println("Amount:");
                amount = sc.nextDouble();
                transac.transaction(accountNo, operation, amount);
                break;

            case "3":
                System.out.println("Account Number:");
                accountNo = sc.nextLong();
                operation = "showInfo";
                transac.transaction(accountNo, operation, 0);
                break;

            case "q":
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong choice!!");
            }
        } while (choice != "q");
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions, improvements on readability, OOP approach, and design.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things I would do differently:

1. Store your list of `Balance` objects in a map of type `HashMap<Long, Balance>` using the account number as a key. This way you don't have to loop through your entire list to find the `Balance` you need. If you do decide to keep the loop, consider getting rid of the iterator and using the enhanced for-loop syntax.
2. Create an enum for your transaction types:
   `enum TransactionType { OPEN, WITHDRAW, DEPOSIT INFO }`
   This will protect you from typos, and in the `operation()` method, it will let you `switch` on the enum value and enable you to get rid of the long `if-else` control structure.
3. There's a concurrency issue. Multiple threads accessing the same `Balance` could result in amounts being withdrawn even if the balance is lower than zero. Probably best to synchronize on the `Balance` object that you're modifying.
4. Initializing a new `Bank` for every transaction doesn't seem right. Consider passing it in as a parameter instead.

These are the things I spotted after a cursory reading. I'll give your code a second look if I find some time later.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the basics right first...

After attempting to understand your implementation, these are the gotchas I can spot (some repeated from @Robby Cornelissen's observations too)

1. You can create a `Balance` object from another `Balance` object, i.e. effectively cloning and doubling accounts' numbers.

   - This smell extremely fishy at first, and it's only in the `Bank` class where I realize where the root cause lie: the `searchAccount()` method. Will explain more below.
2. Your `Balance` class holds a reference to a `Scanner` instance on `System.in`, something that is unused and does not belong there.
3. Your `Balance` class seems to know how to output to the console.

   - Generally speaking, model classes will not interact directly to outputs, be it the console or a file.
4. Your `Bank` class declares an `ArrayList` of `Balance` objects, there are better implementations for this as suggested by @Robby Cornelissen.
5. Every time you search for a `Balance` (object), you are creating a new `Balance` (object) just to check if the account number is the same (more below).
6. Your `Bank` does not keep track of `Transaction`s.

   - In Real Life, a `Bank` will know about `Balance`s and `Transaction`s.
7. Conversely, your singular `Transaction` object creates a `Bank` for its entire lifetime and sole usage.

   - In Real Life, a `Transaction` will 'belong' to a `Bank` and it shouldn't be telling the `Bank` what to do.
8. Your "checks" for `transactionType.equalsIgnoreCase("...")` inside your `operation()` method are exactly what methods are for (more below).
9. Similar to a previous point, your `Transaction` class also seem to know how to output to the console.

---

**Iterating through a collection of `Balance` objects**

Following @Robby Cornelissen's suggestion of using a `HashMap`, you will not need to create 'dummy' `Balance` objects just to compare account numbers. Alternatively, your `Balance` class can have a method `public boolean hasAccountNumber(long accountNum)` to perform this check, instead of doing it within your `Bank` class.

**Understanding methods**

Setting a `String` `transactionType`, comparing it case-insensitive to some values inside `operation()`, and then performing the appropriate steps is convoluted. Just have methods like `withdraw(...)` or `deposit(...)` with the relevant arguments and call them from your `BankDemo` class. There is no simpler way to describe this.